# HDFStore and querying by attributes

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I am currently running a parameter study in which the results are returned as pandas DataFrames. I want to store these DFs in a HDF5 file together with the parameter values that were used to create them (parameter `foo` in the example below, with values `'bar'` and `'foo'`, respectively).

I would like to be able to query the HDF5 file based on these attributes to arrive at the respective DFs - for example, I would like to be able to query for a DF with the attribute `foo` equal to `'bar'`. Is it possible to do this in HDF5? Or would it be smarter in this case to create a multiindex DF instead of saving the parameter values as attributes?

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2],
                     'col_2': [3, 4]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [5, 6],
                     'col_2': [7, 8]})

store = pd.HDFStore('file.hdf5')

store.put('table_1', df_1)
store.put('table_2', df_2)

store.get_storer('table_1').attrs.foo = 'bar'
store.get_storer('table_2').attrs.foo = 'foo'

store.close()
```